# Rename [aaaaaa] → [a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the tag for ***AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! — A Reckless Disregard for Gravity***. ([Yes, that is the game's official title](http://www.dejobaan.com/aaaaa/))

- [aaaaaa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aaaaaa) → [a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity) (32)

I tried coming up with a few different names, but this one seemed to make the most sense considering the length restrictions. Renaming and synonymizing seems to be the best option.

---

<sub>*Funnily enough, the official title [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) is exactly 25 characters.</sub>

Comment: to add to the *footnote, the official title also follows a clear pattern with the upper and lower case A's (U-L: 1-4, 2-3, 3-2, 4-1, 5-0). not too important, but I found it interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now done:

- [aaaaaa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aaaaaa) → [a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity)

Answer (score 13):

I support this proposal.
It would also prevent confusion with the (pseudo-)sequals *AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! for the Awesome* and *AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! (Force = Mass x Acceleration)*

Comment: Do the pseudo sequels have tags for them? Or have no questions been asked about them

Comment: I was thinking more for the future, but didn't find anything with a search. Not sure if any of the [aaaaaa] questions is for the _for the Awesome_. I think the two are very similar.

Comment: Having played them, I can confirm that all 3 are fairly similar. *Force = Mass x Acceleration* is the tilt-enabled iOS version.